# simulating user input to twilio voice with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, twilio

I am trying to simulate user input with Twilio so I can test our voice system using RSpec. I can create a new call, but the [official Twilio ruby gem](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) doesn't seem to allow me to send digits the way a user could type them.

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
call = @client.calls.create({
  from: '+1555550000',
  to: '+15555559999',
  url: 'www.example.com/twilio-endpoint'
})
```

This returns a call object which I would expect you could send digits to, but you can't. You can send digits when starting the call by passing a `:send_digits` key, but once it's been started, you're out of luck. We need to interact with the phone menu and so forth.

There's a gem called [Twilio Test Kit](https://github.com/pgib/twilio-test-toolkit) that used to make this easy, but it was abandoned by its maintainer ages ago. What are people doing to feature test their Twilio voice apps?

**Update**: I should have added this to the original post -- but I am looking to write feature tests that may look something like

```
expect(call).to play_voice_recording('path/to/recording.wav')
call.dial(123)
expect(call).to say('confirmed successfully')
call.dial(0)
expect(call).to say('transferring to operator')
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The call object is really a wrapper around a [call resource in the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call). You can update a [call's state using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state), but that only allows you to redirect the call to another URL that returns [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) or cancel or complete the call.

Presumably your `/twilio-endpoint` is returning [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) that includes a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) that you are trying to test the user response to. When a user enters digits in the phone in response to that `<Gather>` the next action is for Twilio to POST those digits to the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) of the `<Gather>`. So to test what happens next, you need to send a POST request to the URL you use as the `action` attribute with the [entered digits set as the parameter `Digits`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action-parameters).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @philnash, just added a little more details to my question. Hoping you can iterate over that! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of an up to date gem that works like Twilio Test Kit did. If you want to test your flow like that, then I recommend forking it and getting it up to date.